# Drawing parallelogram in a flowchart with the psmatrix enviroment

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to draw flowcharts and I looked at a few packages. As I'm more familiar with `pstricks` I chose it, and as I checked the examples I'm trying to draw it with the `psmatrix` environment.

Our teacher has told us that the "Initializations" should be written in a parallelogram, and when I tried to draw that in my flowchart I had no idea of what syntax should I use for a parallelogram!

Is there any specific command for that?

Should I use `\psdiabox` with a particular angle in order to get the parallelgram? If yes, how should I define the angle?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to draw where I want to have the red box - "Initialization" - as a parallelogram instead of a rectangle.

[image]

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{pstricks}‎
‎\usepackage{pst-node}‎
‎\usepackage{pst-blur}‎
‎\definecolor{Pink}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}‎
‎\pagestyle{empty}‎
‎\begin{document}‎


‎\vspace{0.5cm}‎
‎\small‎‎‎
  ‎\psset{shadowcolor=black!70,blur=true}‎
  ‎\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.4,colsep=0.5]‎
    ‎\psovalbox{Begin} \\‎
    ‎\psframebox[‎,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red‎]{Initialisations} \\‎
    ‎\psdiabox{Special} &‎
       ‎\psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP1} & \psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP2} \\‎
    ‎\psframebox{Action 1} \\‎
    ~‎\\‎
    ‎\psframebox{Action 2} \\‎
    ‎\psovalbox{End}‎
    % ‎Links‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{No}}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{4,1}{6,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}‎
    ‎\ncline{->}{3,2}{3,3}‎
    ‎\ncbar[angleA=-90,armB=0,nodesepB=0.25]{->}{3,3}{4,1}‎
  \end{document}
```

Comment: `pst-node` might be useful too. Could you provide a screenshot of something similar to what you're trying to produce?

Comment: @cmhughes I did put an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-3d}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\definecolor{Pink}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\TBox
\newcommand\psParaBox[2][]{{
  \psset{framesep=5pt,gangle=60,#1}%
  \sbox\TBox{\psTilt{\psk@gangle}{\psframebox{\phantom{ #2}}}}%
  \usebox\TBox%  
  \rput(-0.5\wd\TBox,\dimexpr 0.5\ht\TBox-0.5ex\relax){ #2}}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \psset{shadowcolor=black!70,blur}
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.4,colsep=0.5]
    \psovalbox{Begin} \\
    \psParaBox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40]{Initialisations} \\
    \psdiabox{Special} &
       \psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP1} & \psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP2} \\
    \psframebox{Action 1} \\
    ~\\
    \psframebox{Action 2} \\
    \psovalbox{End}
    % Links
    \ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}
    \ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}
    \ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{No}}
    \ncline{->}{4,1}{6,1}
    \ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}
    \ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}
    \ncline{->}{3,2}{3,3}
    \ncbar[angleA=-90,armB=0,nodesepB=0.25]{->}{3,3}{4,1}
  \end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert for definig the parallelogram in trees .

Comment: @ Herbert You designed both of these parallelograms ,would you please tell me  what's different between these two in addition to their names

Comment: @Negin: the code. the first one defines it on a low level and the second one on a user level, which makes the code more readable.

Comment: With the first code I can get a parallelogram but with the second one which you told me has defined the shape  on user level I can't get it and my output is still a rectangle ! Should I change anything in this code?

Comment: did you viewed the pdf output?

Comment: I got it, you run `xelatex` and then it doesn't work, looks like a bug in the `xdvipdfmx` driver, I'll have a look

Comment: Yes I viewed the PDF output but the shape of initialization box was a rectangle .

Comment: OK , so I would ask it in a persian forum ,since I should use xelatex in order to run the xepersian package .Thank you Herbert

Answer (score 2):

The following defines `\psparallelogram[<options>]{<stuff>}` that works in the same way `\psdiabox` and `\psframebox` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\definecolor{Pink}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8}

% ================================
% Source: http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2009/006766.html

\makeatletter
\newdimen\psparallelogramsep
\def\psset@parallelogramsep#1{\pssetlength\psparallelogramsep{#1}}
\psset@parallelogramsep{3mm}
\def\psparallelogrambox{\pst@object{psparallelogrambox}}
\def\psparallelogrambox@i{\pst@makebox\psparallelogrambox@ii}
\def\psparallelogrambox@ii{%
    \begingroup
    \pst@useboxpar
    \pst@dima=\pslinewidth
    \advance\pst@dima by \psframesep
    \pst@dimc=\wd\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimc by \pst@dima
    \pst@dimb=\dp\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimb by \pst@dima
    \pst@dimd=\ht\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimd by \pst@dima
    \setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{%
        \ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi
        \begin@ClosedObj
        \addto@pscode{%
            \psk@cornersize
            \pst@number\pst@dima neg
            \pst@number\pst@dimb neg
            \pst@number\pst@dimc
            \pst@number\pst@dimd .5
            \pst@number\psparallelogramsep
            \tx@Parallelogram}%
            \def\pst@linetype{2}%
            \showpointsfalse
        \end@ClosedObj
        \box\pst@hbox
        \ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi%
    }%
    \ifpsboxsep\dp\pst@hbox=\pst@dimb\ht\pst@hbox=\pst@dimd\fi
    \leavevmode\box\pst@hbox
    \endgroup%
}

% From the Frame and Rect PostScript macros
\pst@def{Parallelogram}<{%
/ParallelogramA {
x1 pgs sub y1 moveto
x1 y2 lineto
x2 pgs add y2 lineto
x2 y1 lineto
x1 pgs sub y1 lineto
closepath} def
%
/pgs ED
CLW mul
/a ED
3 -1 roll
2 copy gt { exch } if
a sub
/y2 ED
a add
/y1 ED
2 copy gt { exch } if
a sub
/x2 ED
a add
/x1 ED
1 index 0 eq {pop pop ParallelogramA } { OvalFrame } ifelse}>
\makeatother

\def\pspbox[#1]#2{\makebox[#1]{\psparallelogrambox{#2}}}

% ================================


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


\vspace{0.5cm}
\small
  \psset{shadowcolor=black!70,blur=true}
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.4,colsep=0.5]
    \psovalbox{Begin} \\
    %\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{Initialisations} \\
    \psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{Initialisations} \\
    \psdiabox{Special} &
       \psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP1} & \psframebox[shadow=true]{Call to SP2} \\
    \psframebox{Action 1} \\
    ~\\
    \psframebox{Action 2} \\
    \psovalbox{End}
    % Links
    \ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}
    \ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1}
    \ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{No}}
    \ncline{->}{4,1}{6,1}
    \ncline{->}{6,1}{7,1}
    \ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}
    \ncline{->}{3,2}{3,3}
    \ncbar[angleA=-90,armB=0,nodesepB=0.25]{->}{3,3}{4,1}
  \end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

The source for the parallelogram was taken from the PStricks mailing entry on [Parallelogram in trees](http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2009/006766.html).